# How to solve a specific conflict automatically?

Tags: c, git, git-merge-conflict

Assume, I have a file in a commit:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x;

    return 0;
}
```

Then, create 2 branches from that commit. Let's call them `branchA` and `branchB`.

Make the following diff in `branchA`, add a new variable `yy`:

```c
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(){
     int x;
+    int yy;
     return 0;
 }
```

And in `branchB`, let's rename `x` variable as `xx`:

```c
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(){
-    int x;
+    int xx;

     return 0;
 }
```

It is **obvious** that, when I **merge** these 2 branches, I want the final file as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int xx;
    int yy;
    return 0;
}
```

That includes both diffs; renaming a variable and adding a new variable.

However, when I want to merge, git creates conflicts like that.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
<<<<<<< HEAD
    int xx;
=======
    int x;
    int yy;
<<<<<<< branchA

    return 0;
}
```

It is the scenario that I had to solve many conflicts that is not really conflict according to me. I mean, it can be automatically solved. I don't want to solve the conflicts manually at this scenario anymore. How can I handle this situation?

To sum up, is there a way to solve the conflicts automatically that are automatically solvable?

Comment: Solve it manually.  You really don't want the computer trying to take a stab even when it looks obvious to you.  In a much larger, more complex project, you really need to know when two adjacent lines were modified on separate branches,  and you just need to get used to dealing with it.  Without this, weird bugs can be introduced without you even knowing.  Because when's the last time you merged a 6-month long feature, resolved the conflicts and _then_ went and reviewed all the non-conflicts to see if weird stuff happened?  Never, right?  Exactly.

Comment: Really? Currently, I already solve it manually and looking a better way. I don't agree with you about double checking. Let me tell you what I think about this. Think a scenario that there are 2 blank lines between `x` and `return` lines instead of 1 and add new variable near to `return` statement. There is no conflict. If double checking is necessary for adjacent line changes, it has to be always necessary. Always create conflict because we need to double check. C'mon we are developers.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the conflict should not occur. From a logical point of view, these are two separate lines and a conflict should arise only if there were changes on the same lines of code.

Unfortunately, there is an exception with git when it comes to adjacent lines like in the example you gave. In such a case, git will inform of a conflict. If you were to use another revision control tool such as SVN then the merge would succeed without any conflicts.

The reason as to why git does this is not fully known. There are assumptions that it was designed as a feature so that you would be forced to double-check your code before the merge since those adjacent lines of code might be somehow allegedly connected contextually. That's all.

However, there is a tool that can help you "overrun" this "feature" and enable you to do the merge without conflicts in the case of adjacent line changes. You may find it here: https://github.com/paulaltin/git-subline-merge